tokio::BufReader.next_line().await never resolved, execution paused forever
I am very new to rust (literally learnt it two weeks ago) and I've decided to make a faster node package manager (like npm) as my first project.
On the way, I have encountered many issues which I've resolved in the following manner-

There is only one seemingly popular, well maintained & reputed crate for downloading files from the internet, that is reqwest. But it does not seem to be having a progress bar for download.
So I implemented my own downloader with progress bar logic using tokio::Command::new("wget").args(["--show-progress", "-q"])  and tokio::BufReader() on its stderr to read the output of it and display the progress bar with indicatif

I could not find any way of running multiple async functions (futures, in my case downloads) in parallel.
So I am relying on ChatGPT code which goes like this-
   async fn main() {
     let stream = futures::stream::iter(0..1000).map(|i| { download().await });
     let buffer = stream.buffer_unordered(CONCURRENT_DOWNLOADS_COUNT);
     while Some(deps) in buffer.next().await {
       println!("{}", deps); 
       // deps because download function returns a list of dependencies of the package to further download
     }
   }

It creates 1000 awaited download functions ahead of time & stores them in an array, then pools them concurrently.

But the download functions have to the same & for all.
So I have added Arcs, Mutexes & broadcasts (mpmc from tokio) & its working with no errors.


But the problem is in the download function
/* ...wget process created here... */
let reader = BufReader::new(wget.stderr.unwrap());
let mut lines = reader.lines()
while Ok(Some(line)) in lines.next_line().await {
  println!("{}", line); // this never executes
  /* ...extracting percent complete from
    wget progress bar output here... */
}
println!("complete"); // runtime never comes here

As far as i have investigated lines.next_line().await pauses for ever, it never resolves.
This exact code works outside of stream.iter(0..1000).map(...), ex- in a separate file, but when put inside the #2 format, it does not work
I have been trying for days & days together but I have never been able to figure out what exactly is wrong. Please help me fix this issue. I can give my full code if needed. But, please I really need help.

"There is only one seemingly popular, well maintained & reputed crate for downloading files from the internet" - very very wrong. Check out curl, ureq, isahc, and probably many more.

About showing progress using reqwest - a simple search shows many results, e.g. https://gist.github.com/Tapanhaz/096e299bf060607b572d700e89a62529.

Please create a Minimal Reproducible Example.
